# Restore data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I accidentally went into my phone and deleted my phone from Find My iPhone, I was surprised to see that all my photos and contacts and app were deleted, I want to restore my old data back, how can I do that?

Comment: That's a rather strange result of disabling "find my iPhone". How exactly did you remove your phone from "find my iPhone"?

Comment: I read it as "remote deleted" it, as opposed to removed it. Didn't know you could do it from the device you're on right now.

Comment: @patrix I think Rodaina erase the iPhone form the tool available on Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from a previous backup saved in your computer (where is located iTunes) or from an iCloud backup. 
Both the procedures can be done if and only if you previously completed a backup.

**Restore from an iCloud backup**

1. On your iOS device, go to Settings > General > Software Update. If a newer version of iOS is available, follow the onscreen instructions to download and install it.
2. Make sure you have a recent backup to restore from.
3. On your device: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage, then tap a device listed under Backups to see the date and size of its latest backup.
4. In the Setup Assistant, proceed to “Set up your device,” tap Restore from a Backup, then sign in to iCloud.
5. Proceed to “Choose backup,” then choose from a list of available backups in iCloud.